# Doctrine2, bad syntax for UNIQUE Index, SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to setup Doctrine2 inside my project, it works fine, but I have a issue while generating schema with columns option: 'unique=true'

my Entity :

```
<?php
namespace Entities\Test;
/**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="")
* @Table(name="test")
*/
Class Test {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer",unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
     private $test;
}
```

Then, I just use the console command :

```
orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

It return some nice SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL, test NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_D87F7E0CBF396750 ON test (id) WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_D87F7E0CD87F7E0C ON test (test) WHERE test IS NOT NULL;
```

But when I execute it (--force), I get an error :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_D87F7E0CBF3
96750 ON test (id) WHERE id IS NOT NULL':

SQLSTATE [42000, 156]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Serve
r]Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot cl▒ 'WHERE'.
```

It seems that this syntax is for SQLServer >= 2008, but I'm working with SQLServer2005, so I added the good Platform in my options array :

```
    $conn = array(
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'user' => '****_dev',
        'password' => '*******',
        'host' => '*.*.*.*',
        'dbname' => 'dbname',
        'platform' => new Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2005Platform(),
    );

    $this->em = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

But it do not change anything to the SQL code, I still have this 'incorrect syntax near WHERE'

I work with the last stable version of doctrine, downloaded with composer and I tried it in a new clean project, it still the same, I searched a lot for a similar issue, but didn't find anything, I think I missed something.

Any help would be welcome !

Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it, but I'm not satisfied by it,
I just commented thoses lines in Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServerPlatform.php

```
public function getCreateIndexSQL(Index $index, $table)
{
    $constraint = parent::getCreateIndexSQL($index, $table);

//        if ($index->isUnique() && !$index->isPrimary()) {
//        $constraint = $this->_appendUniqueConstraintDefinition($constraint, $index);
//        }

return $constraint;
```